# How to match multiple string arguments efficiently in R

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching

```
tab1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 42, 2, 88, 432, 9584), name = c("apple", "banana",
                                                             "apple", "mango",
                                                             "mango", "apple"))
> tab1
    id   name
1    1  apple
2   42 banana
3    2  apple
4   88  mango
5  432  mango
6 9584  apple
```

I have a `data.frame` named `tab1` that contains the dictionary for finding the `id`s associated with different patterns.

For example, suppose I want to find the `id`s that are associated with the pattern `"apple"`

```
> tab1[which(tab1$name %in% "apple"), ]$id
[1]    1    2 9584
```

or with the pattern `"mango"`,

```
> tab1[which(tab1$name %in% "mango"), ]$id
[1]  88 432
```

I would like to store these `id`s in a new `data.frame` where the `id`s are separated by `|` like this:

```
  pattern       id
1   apple 1|2|9584
2   mango   88|432
3   peach       NA
```

Suppose I have a very long list of patterns (say, over 1 million patterns) that I want to match with those in `tab1`, what's a quick way of doing this in R without relying on for loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 tab1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 42, 2, 88, 432, 9584), name = c("apple", "banana",
                                                             "apple", "mango",
                                                             "mango", "apple"))

pattern<-c("apple","mango","peach","orange")



rbind(aggregate(.~name,data=tab1[tab1$name %in% pattern,] ,FUN = function(x){paste0(x,collapse = "|")}),
      data.frame(name=pattern[!pattern %in% tab1$name],id=NA)
)
    name       id
1  apple 1|2|9584
2  mango   88|432
3  peach     <NA>
4 orange     <NA>
```

Comment: This is not what I'm asking for. If I have a vector of `pattern`s, how can I quickly extract the corresponding `id`s in `tab1`? It's possible that a `pattern` is not found in `tab1`.

Comment: please see the update

Comment: Thanks. If I had an extra column in `tab1`, i.e., `tab1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 42, 2, 88, 432, 9584), name = c("apple", "banana",
                                                             "apple", "mango",
                                                             "mango", "apple"),
                   key = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "D", "C"))`, how might your code change to reflect this?

Comment: not very sure about the things to do with the new column, to collapse them?